# Webmin terminating turn service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webmin

I have a painstakingly correctly configured TURN server set-up on Ubuntu 20.04 server with Webmin/Virtualmin running.

The problem is that webmin is seemingly issuing random `kill -15` command to the coturn systemd service.

```
● coturn.service - coTURN STUN/TURN Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/coturn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/coturn.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2022-06-19 17:26:11 CST; 17s ago
```

```
# killsnoop-bpfcc
17:26:11  1231501 /usr/share/webm  15   1231079 0
17:26:11  1231501 /usr/share/webm  0    1231079 0
```

The only unique thing about my TURN server install is that I use an override in order to run the server as my nextcloud virtual-server admin user as a means of avoiding having to run the service as "root" to access privileged ports.

`/etc/systemd/system/coturn.service.d/override.conf`

```
[Service]
User=virtualserveradminuser
Group=virtualserveradminuser
```

How can I get webmin to stop terminating coturn?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  Problem: user error (as usual)

Because of my override to run TURN as a virtual server admin rather than as the default turnserver user, I inadvertently ran against a handy & useful security feature of Virtualmin that I forgot that I had previously set.

In virtualmin under `System Settings // Virtualmin Configuration // Server administrator permissions //`

(Turn's port 3478 is not a standard port for virtual server admins to use)

Changing the following option solved my problem... now my turn server is humming along

[image]

thx to the Vmin team for the solution above.